# compressing Log4net output files

Tags: c#, io, log4net

Once `log4net RollingFileAppender` closes a file, how can it be compressed to `zip` (and give it a password)?

If custom `appender` is necessary, which virtual method can handle this?

Comment: yes, but only after log4net closes it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As the Zip function in .NET doesn't support password zipping, then you could use something like [DotNetZip](http://dotnetzip.codeplex.com/)

Take a look at this answer:
https://stackoverflow.com/a/1643348/958701

**Updated with example**

You could get the log file path by doing something like this:

```
appenderFilePath = ((Hierarchy)LogManager.GetRepository()).Root.Appenders.OfType<RollingFileAppender>().FirstOrDefault();
```

This only returns the first appender in the collection. So if you have more than one appender, then remove the `FirstOrDefault()` and you'll get all the appender.

Then you should be able to zip the file with something like this using DotNetZip:

```
using (var zip = new ZipFile())
{
    zip.Password = "VerySecret!!";
    zip.AddFile(appenderFilePath);
    zip.Save("logs.zip"); 
}
```